# Does assigning to the same name (e.g. in a loop) free previously used memory in R?

Tags: r

If `a <- iris`, does `a <- 1; gc()` free the previously used memory (i.e. the memory used to store iris as `a`) ?

The reason I suspect it may not (at least not perfectly), is because I am working with the same object names in a 15,000 iteration loop. And very slowly ram usage is building after each iteration, despite `gc()` being called at the end of each iteration.

I cannot understand why this would happen

In case it is useful, here is the loop

```
for (i in starting_index:finishing_index) {
  pdf_path <- paste0("../pdfs/", packages[i], ".pdf")
  manual_pdf <- pdf_text(pdf_path)
  one_manual_pdf <- manual_pdf %>% unlist %>% paste0(., collapse="")
  temp <- one_manual_pdf %>% str_split("topics:")
  length_temp <- temp[[1]] %>% length
  relevant_temp <- temp[[1]] %>% .[(2):(length_temp)] %>% unlist %>% paste0(., collapse="")

  relevant_temp <- relevant_temp %>% 
    strsplit(., "\nstr                                                                      ",
             fixed = TRUE) %>%
    .[[1]] %>% .[1]

  relevant_temp <- relevant_temp %>% str_remove(., "(\\d+)$")

  fns <- relevant_temp %>% strsplit(. , " ") %>% unlist %>% {.[!grepl("\n", .)] } %>% 
    { .[!(nchar(.) == 1 | nchar(.) == 0)] } %>% gsub("\n", "", .) %>% gsub("\r", "", .)

  pgs <- rep(packages[i], length(fns))

  data_for_one <- data.frame(pgs, fns, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  if(!dir.exists("../output")) { shell("cd .. && mkdir output") }

  filename <- paste0("../output/", arguments[1], "pfd.csv")
  write.table(data_for_one, filename, append=TRUE, sep=",", 
              row.names=FALSE, col.names=!file.exists(filename))

  gc()

}
```

Comment: *same object names in a 15,000 iteration loop* ... Please show us this loop code so we can provide a second opinion. If RAM is slowly building, likely you are growing an object (vector/matrix/data frame) in the loop.

Comment: @Parfait done .

Comment: Yes it does.  Memory leak may happen because of a package, but also you may just be seeing R provision more memory, which happens normally.  But you should never see running out of memory if everything is working.

Comment: Where do you see *very slowly ram usage is building*? Try `print(gc())` and check if bytes increase with each iteration.

Comment: @Parfait I was using task manager. I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, in this case, the [memory leak that affected the pdftools R library](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools/issues/64) was stemming from [poppler](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/issues/818), a c++ dependency of R's `pdftools` library

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to run `gc()` yourself. R will automatically run the garbage collection when it needs space.

```
library(pryr)

a <- iris
object_size(a)
> object_size(a)
7.2 kB


a <- 1
object_size(a)
> object_size(a)
56 B
```

Memory problems can appear you want to return objects that capture environments, like formulas, because the memory will stay allocated this way.

```
   leakfunction <- function() {
     x <- runif(100000, 0, 1)
     a ~ b
    }
```

I do not see a problem in your function.